# Disable the comment path site-wide

Tags: 6, comments, advertising

Is it possible somehow to completely disable the `/comment/` path on a Drupal 6 site?

Our site really doesn't need comments and despite having disabled comments on all content types and removing any comment hooks in our theme (someone else developed the site with comments in mind, but we have found that we don't need them, users don't use them, and they only bring in spam to clean up)  we still get pretty regular stream of spam hitting the `/comment/reply/[some_content_id]` paths and while we have a Mollom taking care of the spam for us, I am wondering if its possible to turn those bots away before they have a chance to leave their droppings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while now since I've used D6 but can't you just disable the comments module?

Alternatively what about just blocking /comment with htaccess ([SO thread on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173693/block-one-specific-url-by-htaccess-cannot-be-that-hard))?

Comment: yeah, the obvious was completely evading me for the moment. Thanks.